# replace a class using $animate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-animate

I am using angular and angular-animate with the $animate service.
If I have the following:

```
<div ng-class="myClass"></div>
```

and my controller contains a model for myClass (`$scope.myClass='bigger';`), changing `$scope.myClass` will change the class on the div.
I want to simulate this behavior using the $animate service. The only class-related methods I have are `addClass()` and `removeClass()`. I was expected to find something like `replaceClass()`.
More than that, I need a callback when the animation ends. The two options of mimicking the behavior I can think of are:
(remove class and add class happen one after another)

```
$animate.removeClass(element, oldClass, function() {
    $animate.addClass(element, newClass, function() {
        //animation is done by here
    });
});
```

(remove class and add class happen simultaneously)

```
var removeDeferred = $q.defer();
var addDeferred = $q.defer();
$animate.removeClass(element, oldClass, removeDeferred.resolve);
$animate.addClass(element, newClass, addDeferred.resolve);
$q.all([removeDeferred, addDeferred]).then(function() {
    // Animation ends here
});
```

What is the right and the best way to simulate the class replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method `$animate.setClass`. I'm not sure why it doesn't show up in the docs.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ngAnimate/animate.js#L701-L720

`$animate.setClass(element, newClass, oldClass, deferred.resolve)`

Comment: Is it safe to use this undocumented method? Is it going to be deprecated or something like that?

Comment: It is documented now: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/service/$animate

Comment: The doc generator itself is pretty new, they might be tweaking it. Could you accept my answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: Dun't rush me. I'll accept your answer as soon as I verify in on code. Don't worry.